# How to force 2 a href styles inside a div

Tags: html, css, href

I can't style `link 1` different from `link 2`. It's always forcing the style from `.about a`. No matter if I specific set it to another style.

```
<div class="about">
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 1052px;">
    <h2 style="color: #fff">Title</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Text 1 - <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>

            </li>
            <li>
                Text 2 - <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>

            </li>
        </ul></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
  .about a {
  margin-top: 35px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font: 15px/52px 'sans-serif';
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 226px;
  height: 52px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 27px;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; }
```

I've tried something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="linkk">Link</a>

<span class="linkk" a href:#">Link</span>

<a href="#" class="linkk">Link</a>
```

Comment: Can you post an example showing it not working?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you can't style using id rather than class?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want different styles for each link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood of this line: `I can't style link 1 different from link 2`, you want different style for each link.

If it is only two links, you can use `first-child` and `last-child`

```css
.about li:first-child a {
  color: red;
}

.about li:last-child a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="wrapper" style="width: 1052px;">
    <h2 style="color: #fff">Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Text 1 - <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        Text 2 - <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the **[`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)** pseudo-class:

```css
.about li:first-of-type a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="wrapper" style="width: 1052px;">
    <h2 style="color: #fff">Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Text 1 - <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        Text 2 - <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that it needs to be on the parent `<li>` element, rather than simply adding it to `.about a` directly. This is because the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class pertains to siblings, rather than checking for **any** elements of that type in `.about`. **Both** `<a>` elements are the first of their type in their respective `<li>` parents.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.about li:nth-of-type(1) a {
    color: red;
}

.about li:nth-of-type(2) a {
    color: green;
}
```

```css
.about li:nth-of-type(1) a {
    color: red;
}

.about li:nth-of-type(2) a {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="about">
  <div class="wrapper" style="width: 1052">
    <h2 style="color:#fff">Title</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Text 1 - <a href="#"> Link 1 </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        Text 2 - <a href="#"> Link 2 </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```